# Save As, Export, and Anything with the File Dialog Popup Isn't Opening the File Dialog

Tags: export, saving

When I tried to save the first time blender did not open the file dialog so I could tell it where to save my work. I tried save as, save a copy, and exporting and none of them opened the file dialog. I do not want to loose my work.

Version 2.93.1

Comment: What do you mean by the "file explorer"? Blender has its own internal file dialog which opens whenever you open or save a file. See what settings you have under Edit > Preferences > Save & Load. File preview type should be 'Auto' and under 'Interface > Temporary Editors, File Browser should be 'New Window'.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, I meant the file dialog, sorry. But, I do not see anything under "Edit > Preferences > Save & Load" called "File Preview Type" or anything similar and nothing says "Auto".  Also, "Interface > Temporary Editors" File Browser is already set to "New Window".

Comment: What Blender version are you using?  I think File Preview was introduced with Blender 3. It's certainly there in 3.3, 3.5 and 3.6 and is on the second line under Blend Files at the top of the dialog.

Comment: He said he's using Blender 2.93.1